# MPPT 751 15 connect via VE.Direct to Raspberry Pi 3 (Android of Things) but data is unreadable

Tags: android, raspberry-pi3, android-things

In the buffer i got values that can´t convert to text or hex, [98 63 65 -128 3 0 -94 ....]

Somebody knows some Java/Android reading example or results converter to text?

Thanks in advance.

```
while ((count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Read " + count + " bytes from peripheral");
    byte[] lectura=new byte[count];

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        lectura[i]= (buffer[i]);
        Log.w(TAG,lectura[i] + " | " + buffer[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not only read raw data from Raspberry UART, but implement VE.Direct protocol (receive and parse whole message) [link1](http://www.therollinghome.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id=266) [link2](http://www.therollinghome.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/download-attachments/includes/download.php?id=267) (both links from [Solar Controller Hacks and Arduino Integration](http://www.therollinghome.co.uk/2017/02/18/solar-controller-hacks-and-arduino-integration/)  article). Also check [this official documentation](https://www.victronenergy.com/upload/documents/Whitepaper-Data-communication-with-Victron-Energy-products_EN.pdf), [FAQ](https://www.victronenergy.com/live/vedirect_protocol:faq) and examples like [that](https://github.com/physee/Victron.Arduino-ESP8266). Actually you need to convert something like [SerialRead.ino](https://github.com/physee/Victron.Arduino-ESP8266/blob/master/SerialRead.ino) to Android Things Java.

UPD: [Here](https://github.com/winginitau/VictronVEDirectArduino) also is a good example (you need to convert [VEDirect.cpp](https://github.com/winginitau/VictronVEDirectArduino/blob/master/src/VEDirect.cpp) file into java).